# How to display wrapped relative line number in vim

Tags: vim

When I am using Vim to edit a text file, there are long wrapped paragraphs. I have remapped my `j` and `h` keys to navigate lines based on screen lines after wrapping. However, the relative line numbers displayed are still based on the physical line numbers, which introduced gaps. Is there a way to show relative line numbers based on the screen lines so I could still use `j` and `h` to jump to the lines I want directly?

Comment: No, that's impossible.

Comment: @romainl, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is thus off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It would be a better fit on our sister site [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to your `.vimrc` file, then you can use <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to toggle the number.

```
function! NumberToggle()
  if(&relativenumber == 1)
    set norelativenumber
  else
    set relativenumber
  endif
endfunc

nnoremap <leader>nt :call NumberToggle()<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Do you have any idea related to the wrapped lines?